# List view with check box android?

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an sample application using list view with check box. Here is my problem,  when i select any check-box in list-view, then that row has to be deleted from list-view.

Comment: show the code that you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove that row data from the List/Array of the Position` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` of your `Adapter`

Comment: google and developer.android.com has already expanded just try to find.